# FirebaseException: FetchError: Duplicate request while the previous one is pending

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-remote-config

What is the proper way to handle "pending" from a RemoteConfig fetch? I assumed I should wait a little and call it again, but I was wrong. When I call it again it gives me the error.

Logs:

```
FirebaseRemoteConfig - Fetch was unsuccessful:Pending reason:Invalid
```

Error:

```
FirebaseException: FetchError: Duplicate request while the previous one is pending
```

Code:

```
FirebaseRemoteConfig.DefaultInstance.FetchAsync(TimeSpan.Zero).ContinueWith(
    task =>
    {
        if (!task.IsCompleted)
        {
            CustomDebug.LogError("FirebaseRemoteConfig -- Retrieval hasn't finished");
            return;
        }

        var remoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.DefaultInstance;
        var info = remoteConfig.Info;
        if (info.LastFetchStatus != LastFetchStatus.Success)
        {
            CustomDebug.LogErrorFormat("FirebaseRemoteConfig - Fetch was unsuccessful:{0} reason:{1}", info.LastFetchStatus, info.LastFetchFailureReason);
            FetchRemoteConfigAsync().Forget();
            return;
        }

        Debug.Log("FirebaseRemoteConfig -- Fetched Successfully");
        ActivateRemoteConfig();
    }
);
```

Comment: How did you manage to get it work?

Answer (score 0):

As demonstrated in [Get started with Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/get-started?platform=unity), replace **ContinueWith** with **ContinueWithOnMainThread**. This will require you to append

```
using Firebase.Extensions;
```

To your using statements.

Once you have done this, see if just letting the request complete causes the behavior you are looking for.